# matrix normalisation between -1 and 1

Tags: python, matrix

I am using python and I have a matrix and would like to normalize individual columns in it between [-1,1]

```
a = matrix
([[3, 2, 4, 6]
  [4, 5, 6, 5]
  [6, 4, 5, 3]
  [3, 5, 6, 7]])
```

I applied

`a = a / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=0, keepdims=True)`

and the a was normalized between [0,1]

however, I would like to do something like `.apply(lambda x: np.where(x>0,x/x.max(),np.where(x<0,-x/x.min(),x)))` so that it can get normalised between [-1,1] and the zero position is the same.

but it is not possible to use
`.apply`
in a matrix, how can I overcome it?

Comment: Why not take your `[0,1]` normalized matrix, multiply by 2, and then subtract 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[-1, -2, -3]])

maxElement = np.amax(matrix)

new_matrix = matrix/maxElement
print(new_matrix)
```

Find the largest element in the matrix and divide it with all elements

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this probably is not what I am looking for I want it to be done row wise and also would like it to be done so that the positive numbers are divides by the largest positive number , and the negative numbers are divided by the largest negative number. could you help me with that ?

Comment: coloumn wise* not row wise

Comment: @user157522 if we divide the negative numbers with the largest negative number, it will gives you a positive number right?

Comment: Ya right ! sorry what I meant was the absolute value of the largest negative number. That way it would be normalised between -1 and 1